# Как правильно читать данные из сокета QTcpSocket?

Tags: macos, c, qt, сокет

Есть сервер, написанный на `Си`, который отсылает список файлов находящийся в структуре FileList

```
typedef struct tag_file
{
  char *name;
...
} file_st;
file_st *FileList;
...
int i;
for (i = 0; i < FileList_len; i++) {
  send(i32ConnectFD, FileList[i].name, strlen(FileList[i].name), 0);   
}
```

Клиент написан на `Qt` и принимает сообщение таким образом:

```
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(read()));
...
void Client::read()
{
    QString string(tcpSocket->readAll());
    qDebug() << string << endl;
}
```

Проблема в том, что список файлов получается одной строкой, и вывод выглядит примерно так:

> /users/derkode/documents/1/.DS_Store/users/derkode/documents/1/Client.java/users/derkode/documents/1/FormAddFile.java

Вот я и не могу понять - то ли я неправильно отправляю список, или не правильно получаю? Как принять/отправить список частями, чтобы я каждый в отдельности мог обработать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно после каждого имени файла добавлять '\0', признак окончания списка - "\0\0".
При парсинге это учитывайте

Comment: Дело в том, что если я из сервера отправляю пакет с задержкой, к примеру если поставить точку останова в цикле, то клиент принимает как положено частями. Такое ощущение, что сервер разом прогоняет все данные в поток сокета. А сигнал readyRead() у клиента успевает среагировать только один раз.

Comment: Сигнал readyRead() означает, что в буфере есть принятые данные. Вы должны их читать пока не достигнете последнего байта вашего пакета (последнего символа последнего файла из списка).
   Вначале (при первом readyRead) в буфере может быть 100байт, во второй раз - еще 500 и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

не помню где, но уже отвечал на похожий вопрос.
тут пример рабочего QTcpSocket только на python (разницы по сути ни какой)
а именно по твоему вопросу то все довольно просто:
определи для себя формат пакета данных, который будет передавать имена файлов, например так:
длина пакета (2), количество файлов (1) + список файлов: длина имени (2) + имя (N)
или еще проще, если твой клиент/сервер больше ни какими данными не оперирует: длина имени + имя. профит.
P.S: обязательно почитай про сетевые протоколы и [Сетевая модель OSI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI) и все в таком духе, чтобы понять свою очевидную ошибку) удачи!